# Drupal: upload CCK Images before saving the node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've defined a content-type with some text areas and a CCK Upload File (image) field.

When i create a new node, if I upload the image before saving the node, it keeps uploading endlessly.

If I save the node, I re-open it and I upload the image it works in few seconds.

Am I forced to save the nodes before to upload images with CCK Upload Fields in Drupal ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I've had similar troubles. I would recommend looking at your apache server logs and your php logs to see if you can find anything going wrong. Also try it across different browsers and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the CCK Upload File, but the most popular (and by far the most supported and actively developed) way to upload using CCK is [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) (and its image-based counterpart, [ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield)). Both don't exhibit the problem you describe: you can absolutely upload during node creation.

Comment: yeah FileField, is what I meant. Sorry. Well, I'm experiencing this strange bug.